# C#, In a Mysql connection proprety connection.Server and connection.DataSource are always equals or there is a case where are different?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, sqldatasource

In my program I can see these proprietes are always equals, can be different in some exceptional case?

Comment: Would be better if we see yout work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to a different server, the values will be different, but I bet you already knew *that*. Furthermore [the documentation of the `DataSource` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions that the state of the connection (open or closed) can affect its value. I don't know about the `Server` property.

If you are looking for a way to identify "equal" connections, you may want to use the `ConnectionString` property. This is how Connection Pooling determines whether a closed connection can be reused.